# Issue returning a JSON associative array from an ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, system.text.json

I have a Web API method in ASP.NET Core 3.1 that returns an enumerable list of objects:

`public async Task<IEnumerable<MyObject>> Get()`

The Web API returns JSON by default. This has worked fine, until I added a property of type Dictionary<int, object> to MyObject, not realizing that whatever serializer ASP.NET Core 3.1 is using to build the response can't serialize a Dictionary (error is "type Dictionary<int, object> is not supported"). I can reproduce the same error by trying to serialize the Dictionary using the new System.Text.Json library, which is what I'm guessing is being used by the web API to build the JSON response.

Since JsonConvert still serializes Dictionary just fine, it wouldn't be hard to do the serialization manually in the method. But that means making my own JSON response and returning it as a content string, which just seems ... not great.

Is there another associative array type I could be using that the web API can serialize into JSON correctly? Or is there a way to configure the web API to use a JSON serialization library that can handle Dictionary? Or am I just stuck making my own JSON response for this method?

Edit: To be clear, I am curious which of these are possible, what the advantages or disadvantages are to each, so that I might choose a good solution for my circumstance.

Comment: [If only Google could answer this question.](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/)

Comment: In Microsoft's documentation there is an example of how to write a custom `JsonConverter` for `Dictionary<Enum,TValue>`: [Support Dictionary with non-string key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#support-dictionary-with-non-string-key).  You could follow that pattern.  Or, just convert your data model from `Dictionary<int, T>` to `Dictionary<string, T>` which will work.

Comment: @IanKemp Sorry, but I was here to ask not only if each approach was possible, but if it was better or worse than the others. That's specifically something StackOverflow better at than Google, in my experience at least.

Comment: @dbc Thanks, I hadn't even thought of converting the underlying type of the dictionary, because I hadn't realized that it was specifically a non-string key that was at issue. This should work for us without the need for changing the the Json serialization that the API uses.

Comment: Well then you should have specified that in your question.

Comment: @IanKemp My apologies.

Comment: @IanKemp I have updated the question to hopefully better reflect the value of posting it on stack overflow.

Comment: @Jason Sorry if I came across as curt - there are a **lot** of questions asked on Stack Overflow, most of which aren't worth anyone's time, and it gets frustrating dealing with them. You seem like you're actually here to learn, which is exactly what this site is about, and I don't want to discourage that. Just make sure to be as specific as possible in your questions - it helps us to help you.

Comment: @IanKemp I understand the curtness. It's not always obvious to me how I come across, so it's good to learn how to use this resource better. Thanks for taking the time to explain where you were coming from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer comes from @dbc in the comments. I hadn't realized that the System.Text.Json difficulty with serializing Dictionary wasn't with Dictionary generally, but specifically with Dicitonary using a non-string key. It was trivial for us to write a converter to translate the necessary Dictionary to a string-keyed type, and then the built-in JSON serialization handled it just fine.

Thanks, @dbc!