# How to Debug System.Text.Json Deserializer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.text.json

In the case of deserializing JSON data using System.Text.Json where the data doesn't match the target model, it throws a NotSupportedException with no detail whatsoever.

If the data is complex, it can be very difficult to pin-point where the problem occurred.

Is there a way to get some more debug information, or some hint as to which member failed to deserialize?

EDIT

Here's a sample command

```
var result = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ApiResponse<T>>(responseStream, OntraportSerializerOptions.Default, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Error message:

> The collection type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,OntraportApi.Models.ResponseSectionFields]' on 'OntraportApi.Models.ApiResponse`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,OntraportApi.Models.ResponseSectionFields]].Data' is not supported.'

responseStream.Length = 18494, want me to paste it?

Comment: Look at stack trace?

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: Can you give an example of your problem?  When I deserialize JSON with an error, say a string is present when an integer is expected, I get a perfectly useful and descriptive error: *`System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $.widget.window.width | LineNumber: 5 | BytePositionInLine: 22.  System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'String' as a number.`*  The exact position of the error in the JSON stream, as well as the JSONPath path to the error, is present.  Demo fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvDrdO

Comment: I added a sample command and error

Comment: The problem here is that `System.Text.Json` only supports dictionaries with string keys, see [New Asp.NET Core 3.0 Json doesn't serialize Dictionary<Key,Value> #30524](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30524) and [Dictionary with non-string key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#dictionary-with-non-string-key).

Comment: I.e. the problem here is not that the "data doesn't match the target model" but that the serializer doesn't implement serialization of your model, even though Json.NET does.  In this case I was able to track down the problem by [Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22system.text.json%22+The+collection+type+System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%202[System.Int32+is+not+supported.) for the error message + "System.Text.Json".  This is kind of a special case though.  Usually when the JSON doesn't match the model the serializer does report the location and path of the problematic JSON value.

Comment: Oh interesting. I didn't notice those 2 last functions that failed were the only place in the whole API where I was using a non-string dictionary so I didn't notice it! I switched the key to string and now it work thanks!

Comment: Mark as a duplicate of [Issue returning a JSON associative array from an ASP.NET Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63938386/3744182) then?